# While loop breaks before reading next line from input

Tags: c#

I cannot for the life of me get this to work and I know it's going to be something stupid. This code is run on a button click. I want it to run and read multiple lines from a `RichTextBox` input and run the respective code, like a simple programming language that outputs shapes onto a canvas. So far all this does is run the first line on the input and breaks the loop.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
private void run_button(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int lineno = 0;
    int loopline = 0;
    int param = 0;
    string commandinit = commandbox.Text.Trim().ToLower();
    string[] lines = commandinit.Split('\n');

    while (lines[lineno] != null)
    {
        string[] command = lines[lineno].Split(' ', ',');

        if (command[lineno].Equals("moveto") == true)
        {
            if (!Int32.TryParse(command[1], out positionx)) ; //translate string to int
            if (!Int32.TryParse(command[2], out positiony)) ;

            Canvas.xPos = positionx;
            Canvas.yPos = positiony;

            lineno++;
        }

        if (command[lineno].Equals("drawto") == true || command[lineno].Equals("draw") == true)
        {
            if (!Int32.TryParse(command[1], out positionx)) ; //translate string to int
            if (!Int32.TryParse(command[2], out positiony)) ;

            Canvas.toX = positionx;
            Canvas.toY = positiony;
            MyCanvas.DrawLine(Canvas.toX, Canvas.toY);
            Refresh();//refresh display
            Console.WriteLine("COMMAND - LINE DRAWN");

            lineno++;
        }
        if (command[lineno].Equals("circle") == true)
        {
            if (!Int32.TryParse(command[1], out positionx)) ;

            Canvas.sizec = positionx;
            MyCanvas.DrawCircle(Canvas.sizec);
            Refresh();//refresh display
            Console.WriteLine("COMMAND - DRAW CIRCLE");

            lineno++;
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("While loop broken");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for all your help guys. This is my updated code. It works up until the next line is blank, when it crashes on `while (lines[lineno] != null)` with System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

```
private void run_button(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int lineno = 0;
    int loopline = 0;
    int param = 0;
    string commandinit = commandbox.Text.Trim().ToLower();
    string[] lines = commandinit.Split('\n');

    while (lines[lineno] != null)
    {
        string[] command = lines[lineno].Split(' ', ',');

        if (command[0].Equals("moveto") == true)
        {

            if (!Int32.TryParse(command[1], out positionx)) ; //translate string to int                    
            if (!Int32.TryParse(command[2], out positiony)) ;

            Canvas.xPos = positionx;
            Canvas.yPos = positiony;

            lineno++;
        }

        else if (command[0].Equals("drawto") == true || command[0].Equals("draw") == true)
        {
            if (!Int32.TryParse(command[1], out positionx)) ; //translate string to int
            if (!Int32.TryParse(command[2], out positiony)) ;

            Canvas.toX = positionx;
            Canvas.toY = positiony;
            MyCanvas.DrawLine(Canvas.toX, Canvas.toY);
            Refresh();//refresh display
            Console.WriteLine("COMMAND - LINE DRAWN");

            lineno++;
        }
        else if (command[0].Equals("circle") == true)
        {
            if (!Int32.TryParse(command[1], out positionx)) ;

            Canvas.sizec = positionx;
            MyCanvas.DrawCircle(Canvas.sizec);
            Refresh();//refresh display
            Console.WriteLine("COMMAND - DRAW CIRCLE");

            lineno++;
        }

        else if (command[0].Equals("square") == true)
        {
            if (!Int32.TryParse(command[1], out positionshape)) ; //translate string to int

            Canvas.sizes = positionshape;
            MyCanvas.DrawSquare(Canvas.sizes);
            Refresh();//refresh display
            Console.WriteLine("COMMAND - SQUARE DRAWN");

            lineno++;
        }
               
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("While loop broken");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is something of with your blocks and braces `{}`. If you indent your posted code correctly, the closing brace before the last `else` closes the body of the `while loop`

Comment: I think it would be easier to understand what's going on here if you changed to a `switch case`, where the cases are action and the `default case` is breaking the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the code here and it does not execute "only the first line". The while loop do try to keep going. You are, however, double-incrementing the `lineno` variable
For instance, for a "drawto" command: when you do a pass at a `drawto` if (which's true) you increment `lineno`. Then you move over to `circle`, which does nothing, and by the end you do a `loopline = lineno` (which is ok), but then you do `lineno++` again, and that skips a line.

You will eventually move "past the bounds of the array". I'd change it from a while-loop to a for for-loop (since you already know how many lines you're executing).

`for (lineno = 0; lineno < lines.Length; lineno++){ ... }`

What happens to your code? Does it stop, gives you an exception, or will it simply close?

Edit: I'd also consider doing `else if` instead of several `if` statements.
Edit2: Your `else` statement will run EVERY TIME the command is NOT "circle", and will break the loop (I removed the else from my code earlier for testing... sorry) . Consider the `if/else` suggestions from the @Hans Killian. -- I`m also new to this site so still learning how to answer..

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- `while (lines[lineno] != null)` is not working. You're looking for `for(var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)` or simply `foreach(var line in lines)`.
- `if (command..) {..} if (command..) {..} else {..}` will process all if conditions and and the else block for all commands except "circle". You're looking for `if() {} else if() else {}` or `switch()`.
- In the inner block: `if(!Int32..); if(!Int32..);` is not working because of semicolons at the end of the if and the missing braces around the following code block. You're looking for `if(a && b){c}`.

How about this code snipped to start with?

```
    string commandinit = "MoveTo 1 2\r\nDraw 1 2\r\n";
    string[] lines = commandinit.Split('\n');

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        string[] command = line.Trim().Split(' ', ',');

        switch (command[0].Trim())
        {
            case "MoveTo":
            {
                // ParseMoveToCommand(command);
                break;
            }
            case "Draw":
            {
                // ParseDrawCommand(command);
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unknown command");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your indexing when you check for which command the line contains is wrong. You use `lineno`, but it should be `0` since you always want to look at the first word in the line. That's also why it works for the first line, because for the first line, `lineno` is 0.

So when you do

```
if (command[lineno].Equals("moveto") == true)
```

it should be

```
if (command[0].Equals("moveto") == true)
```

(and of course all the other places you use `command[lineno]`

Another issue is that your `else` at the bottom gets activated in all cases where the command isn't `circle`. To make sure you only terminate the loop when no valid command has been found, you should use `else if` and make the structure something like this

```
    if (command[0].Equals("moveto") == true)
    {
    }
    else if (command[0].Equals("drawto") == true || command[0].Equals("draw") == true)
    {
    }
    else if (command[0].Equals("circle") == true)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("While loop broken");
        break;
    }
```

That will make it so you only get into the `While loop broken` section if none of the other ifs have matched.

You might want to use a `switch` statement instead of ifs and elses. It's a bit cleaner, imo.

Comment: Thanks yeah that makes sense. But it's still only running the first line and then breaking the loop. I don't understand why.

Comment: @JJWW I've added a section on use of `else if` to my answer.

Comment: Sorry I'm new on this site. Can I post updated code as a comment or should I edit my initial question?

Comment: @JJWW I meant update the initial question. But I don't know if it's a good idea, when I think about it. Leaving it as it is is also fine.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `if (command[lineno].Equals("circle") == true)` should be `else if (command[lineno].Equals("circle") == true)` in addition what @Hans Killian suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was working from a mixture of different answers which is in the edited code from the question. But changing it to a `for` loop using  `for (lineno = 0; lineno < lines.Length; lineno++)`

updated working code is

```
private void run_button(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int lineno = 0;
            int loopline = 0;
            int param = 0;
            string commandinit = commandbox.Text.Trim().ToLower();
            string[] lines = commandinit.Split('\n');

            for (lineno = 0; lineno < lines.Length; lineno++)
            {

                string[] command = lines[lineno].Split(' ', ',');

                if (command[0].Equals("moveto") == true)
                {

                    if (!Int32.TryParse(command[1], out positionx)) ; //translate string to int                    
                    if (!Int32.TryParse(command[2], out positiony)) ;

                    Canvas.xPos = positionx;
                    Canvas.yPos = positiony;                                      

                }


                else if (command[0].Equals("drawto") == true || command[0].Equals("draw") == true)
                {
                    if (!Int32.TryParse(command[1], out positionx)) ; //translate string to int
                    if (!Int32.TryParse(command[2], out positiony)) ;

                    Canvas.toX = positionx;
                    Canvas.toY = positiony;
                    MyCanvas.DrawLine(Canvas.toX, Canvas.toY);
                    Refresh();//refresh display
                    Console.WriteLine("COMMAND - LINE DRAWN");                   

                }
                else if (command[0].Equals("circle") == true)
                {
                    if (!Int32.TryParse(command[1], out positionx)) ;

                    Canvas.sizec = positionx;
                    MyCanvas.DrawCircle(Canvas.sizec);
                    Refresh();//refresh display
                    Console.WriteLine("COMMAND - DRAW CIRCLE");                    
                }

                else if (command[0].Equals("square") == true)
                {
                    if (!Int32.TryParse(command[1], out positionshape)) ; //translate string to int

                    Canvas.sizes = positionshape;
                    MyCanvas.DrawSquare(Canvas.sizes);
                    Refresh();//refresh display
                    Console.WriteLine("COMMAND - SQUARE DRAWN");                 

                }

                else if (command[0].Equals("rectangle") == true || command[0].Equals("rect") == true) //what happens if draw rectangle command is used
                {
                    if (!Int32.TryParse(command[1], out positionx)) ; //translate string to int
                    if (!Int32.TryParse(command[2], out positiony)) ;

                    Canvas.sizerx = positionx;
                    Canvas.sizery = positiony;
                    MyCanvas.DrawRect(Canvas.sizerx, Canvas.sizery);
                    Refresh();//refresh display
                    Console.WriteLine("COMMAND - DRAW RECTANGLE");                 

                }

                else if (command[0].Equals("colour") == true || command[0].Equals("col") == true || command[0].Equals("color") == true) //changes colour of the pen
                {
                    if (command[1].Equals("red") == true || command[1].Equals("r") == true)
                    {
                        Canvas.P1.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;                        
                    }
                    else if (command[1].Equals("blue") == true || command[1].Equals("blu") == true)
                    {
                        Canvas.P1.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;                        
                    }
                    else if (command[1].Equals("black") == true || command[1].Equals("bla") == true)
                    {
                        Canvas.P1.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;                        
                    }
                    else if (command[1].Equals("green") == true || command[1].Equals("g") == true)
                    {
                        Canvas.P1.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green;                        
                    }
                    else if (command[1].Equals("yellow") == true || command[1].Equals("yel") == true || command[1].Equals("y") == true)
                    {
                        Canvas.P1.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;                        
                    }


                }
                else if (command[0].Equals("loop") == true)
                {
                    loopline = lineno;                    
                }

                else if (command[0].Equals("loop") == true)
                {
                    loopline = lineno;                    
                }
                                
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("While loop broken");
                    break;                    
                }

            }

                        
        }
```

Thanks for all your help